# Make file targetting all C files in a directory

Tags: c, makefile

I want to make some shared library settings using pkg-config that would be applied when any ".c" file is compiled inside a directory. How do I access the name of the file in the make rule?

For example, if these are files in a directory

```
foo1.c
bar.c
foobar.c
```

If I run `make foobar`, I want an object file `foobar` generated and linked to the shared library using the options in pkg-config. I don't want to explicitly write a rule for each file, it should be able to do this for any ".c/.h" file. I think this is possible in make, but I'm not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of your C-files in that directory don't depends on others, you may write such makefile:

```
CC = gcc
LDFLAGS = -l...
DEFINES = -D...
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror ...

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but what do the wildcards "$<" and "$@" represent?

Comment: `$<` is filename (`%.c`), `$@` is target name.